# How to handle Synchronization with the Lambda and S3 Buckets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function written in Python, This function process some file present in the S3 bucket and once process is done, move it to the another S3 Bucket.
This Lambda function is triggered with File Creation on S3 bucket and the scheduler with every 15 min.
But sometimes what happens is that, same file is processed multiple times due to trigger and scheduler,

How can make it sync? If the file creation trigger is running for one file in s3 bucket, that file should be locked and scheduler can't process it.
Simple term:
Trigger:
File Found -> Lock it -> Process it -> Unlock it

So if the scheduler get called and found same file, it can't access it due to lock.

Any help on this?

Comment: Just store another file in S3 with the names of the files you have already processes in it & use it to avoid duplicates

Comment: The scheduled trigger seems redundant; you should consider removing it. Since the function is triggered with every file creation, the S3 bucket would be empty by the time the schedule trigger activates, if every execution happened immediately.

Comment: @t_krill, that's correct, but for a scenario where file process is failed, there should be someone who can process it later, so scheduler is added.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation so just comment down here. I think you are using scheduler for processing failed data is a bad design. You can have a better structure using SQS + SQS dead letter queue + Lambda. It's one of the best practices for processing events and failed events